# Set the position of div according to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div to be scroll upto some height with scrolling.

I am using this code bt its not working for me,please help me out to solve this problem using javascript or css i can't use jquery in my programm
thanks in advance

```
 element.style.position='fixed';
 element.style.scrollTop ='800px';
 element.style.overflow='scroll';

 function Scroll()
  {
    var intY = document.getElementById("impulseadcontainer").scrollTop ;
    console.log("pos"+intY);
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with some code to demonstrate what you're trying to do? Also, if you can't use jQuery, why do you have the `jquery` tag?

Comment: @flowstoneknight No more jquery tag.

Comment: Yes please give in the html and a fiddle of the same so that its easy for others to understand the scenario

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign something to the `scrollTop` attribute in order for it to work.

```
function scroll() {
    document.getElementById("impulseadcontainer").scrollTop = 0; // scrolls to top (set here whatever value you want)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following javascript code.

document.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById('id-of-element').offsetTop);